# From within a decorator, how do I get the name of the PARENT MODULE NAME of an arbitrary function I'm wrapping (Python)

Tags: python, decorator

Let's say I've got a decorator that wraps "func" as shown here:

```py
def my_decorator(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        print(f"Wrapping function {func.__name__} from module {func.parent_module.__name__}")
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
```

It's that "func.parent_module.**name**" part I'm stuck on.

In other words:  "func" could come from anywhere , so if "func" is a function in my_lib.py, how could the decorator retreive that "my_lib" name to report/log/etc?

Edit for clarity:  Getting the function name is no problem, getting the DECORATOR'S parent module is no problem, it's the function's parent name I'm after.

Comment: Did you mean: `func.__module__`?

Comment: Turns out yes, yes I did, thanks!